# How to insert a file at the beginning for another file in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a script: the final goal is to create one text file by taking content from some files and modifying some files.
I have a `fileA` which has some constant content (20 lines) and `fileB` which is created by modifying another files. Now I have to insert all the information from `fileA` at beginning of `fileB`.

Can you some please help me here?

Comment: Assuming your script writes to `stdout`, you can do `{ cat fileA; yourScript; } > fileB`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0):

`cat` command reads and prints the file content as it is. Redirect its output to another file using `>>` (append mode). Repeat the same for the next file

```
cat fileA >> fileC
cat fileB >> fileC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
f=$(mktemp); (head -n 20 fileA ; cat fileB ) > $f; mv $f fileB
```

You can't write directly to fileB, since

```
cat fileA fileB > fileB
```

would destroy fileB for writing immediately before reading. head -n 20 is overly ancient, if you can assert, that fileA will either always have 20 lines exactly, or more lines don't matter.

The *mktemp* will not override existing files, so this is a pretty secure way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this... cat - fileB < fileA > tmp; mv tmp fileB

Example:

$ cat a.sh 
line 1
line 2
line 3

$ cat b.sh 
line a
line b
line c

$ cat - b.sh < a.sh > tmp.sh

$ cat tmp.sh 
line 1
line 2
line 3
line a
line b
line c

$ mv tmp.sh b.sh

$ cat b.sh 
line 1
line 2
line 3
line a
line b
line c
```